# OnNavigatedTo in Prism doesn't trigger from one of pages

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, prism

I faced with the strange behavior of OnNavigatedTo in Prism. It works always on Android, but on iOS it not works for one of the pages. See code:

```
private void OnSpecialtyTapped()
        {
            _navigationService.NavigateAsync($"{nameof(SpecialtyFilterPage)}", useModalNavigation: false);
        }

private void OnLocationTapped()
        {
            _navigationService.NavigateAsync($"{nameof(PlacesFilterPage)}", useModalNavigation: false);
        }


private void OnTakeChosenSpecialties()
        {
            var parameters = new NavigationParameters
            {
                //{"ChosenSpecialtiesIds", CheckedSpecialties.Select(s => s.Id).ToList()}
            };

            _navigationService.GoBackAsync(parameters);
        }

private void OnTakeChosenPlaces()
        {
            var parameters = new NavigationParameters
            {
                //{"ChosenPlaces", CheckedPlaces.Select( p => new Models.PlaceParameter {Id=p.Id, Type=Convert.ToString(p.Type)}).ToList()}
            };

            _navigationService.GoBackAsync(parameters);
        }

public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
        {
            if ( parameters.ContainsKey("ChosenSpecialtiesIds") )
            {
                var chosenSpecialtiestIds = parameters["ChosenSpecialtiesIds"] as List<string>;
                if ( chosenSpecialtiestIds == null ) return;
                _filter.Services.Clear();

                foreach ( var specialtiestId in chosenSpecialtiestIds )
                {
                    _filter.Services.Add(new ServiceParameter { Id = specialtiestId });
                }
            }
            else if ( parameters.ContainsKey("ChosenPlaces") )
            {
                var chosenPlaces = parameters["ChosenPlaces"] as List<PlaceParameter>;
                if ( chosenPlaces == null ) return;
                _filter.Places.Clear();

                _filter.Places = chosenPlaces;
            }

        }
```

It works with Specialty and doesn't work on iOS with Places. I am using Prism 6.2.0 and Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3.193. I can't use newer version because of some bug.

Comment: Can your provide more detail like a link to a sample that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @DanS.
Here you can find more details:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/255644

Comment: As Brian already indicated on that thread and as I indicated in the previous comment you need to provide a sample that reproduces the issue. If nobody can reproduce the issue it makes it very difficult to help you.

Comment: @DanS.
Please see on progress in Xamarin forum.

Comment: You really should focus on getting help here or there. Again you need a sample that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @DanS.
Sorry for this mess, I just want to get best. 
Please look into the new sample on Xamarin forum, it has progressed.